# Spyne with Flask application context

Tags: python, flask, spyne

I have Flask application and need to add SOAP server functionality to integrate with some services. The Spyne library was choosen for SOAP. I found how to combine Flask and Spyne wsgi apps together using werkzeug.wsgi.DispatcherMiddleware. But now I faced with issue of getting Flask app config inside Spyne service views. I usually use `current_app.config['FOO']` to get Flask app settings, but when request comes to Spyne wsgi app I have no Flask application context. I need an advice how to deal with it, please.

Comment: I'm using Flask but don't know Spyne, just a suggestion: how about using a config file shared between Flask and Spyne? See [Flask Configuring from Files](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/config/#configuring-from-files).

Comment: Yes, I can. But my app has a few configs and there are some configuration logic. The better is to share read-only config instance. I will try. My mind is stuck in thought that I alway have flask app context, it is very handy.

Comment: Hi, Spyne maintainer here. Can you provide a working example? I skimmed over the Flask app config page but did not find much about your specific use case.

Comment: Hello Spyne maintainers! I've created an example to show you my use case. This is the line I want to access flask app config http://goo.gl/N3HzEh

Comment: Now I found solution to `set ctx.udc.config` to `flask_app.config` on `wsgi_call` event. But I dont like it. I think how to integrate Spyne views to Flask natively.

Comment: I've created a pull request with flask example https://github.com/arskom/spyne/pull/286

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to get hold of that config object outside of the Flask context, but if you can, you can setattr anything to the `Application` instance which is acccessible via `ctx.app` within Spyne's @rpc context.

Comment: This is the solution I choose. On `wsgi_call` I set `ctx.udc.config` to `flask_app.config`, and use it wherever I need.

Comment: This is the right way to do it. If you can share your code, I can put it in the Spyne examples directory in the main repo. I don't see the wsgi_call event in the example you shared.

Comment: I've created a pull request with flask example https://github.com/arskom/spyne/pull/286

Comment: I created a pull request in Flask-Spyne to use Flask app context. This way, I have full access to Flask context, not only config. https://github.com/rayrapetyan/flask-spyne/pull/3

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming a shared config file approach is not possible for you, otherwise I would go for import from the config file in the spyne 
e.g from config import blah blah
just a thought